# PQexecparams - Not supporting third parameters in binding array

Tags: c++, database, postgresql

I am newbie in postgresql and trying to insert the values in db with PQexecparams. When i bind two parameters in values array it works perfectly but when i move to three it shows an error 
"INSERT failed: cannot allocate memory for output buffer"
Here is my code:

```
     void InsertBinaryRec(PGconn *conn, double *valueX, char *nameString, double *valueY)
{

        int paramLengths[10];
        int paramFormats[3] = { 1, 0, 1 }; 

        const char* values[3] = {(const char *) valueX, nameString, (const char *) valueY };
        cout << "ya phr gya????" << endl;
        paramLengths[3] = 10 ;
        PGresult *res = PQexecParams(conn,
                           "INSERT INTO testData (X, NAME, Y) VALUES ($1::bytea, $2::TEXT, $3::bytea)",
                           3,           
                           NULL,         
                           values,
                           paramLengths,
                           paramFormats,
                           3);           

        if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "INSERT failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
                PQclear(res);
                CloseConn(conn);
        }
        cout << "Insert testData record - OK\n";

  PQclear(res);
}
```

Comment: Are the database fields really `bytea` ?

Comment: Yes, i have set it bytea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `paramLengths` like this:

```
int paramLengths[3] = { (int)sizeof(double), 0, (int)sizeof(double) };
```

It is rather weird to store the binary representation of a double precision value as a `bytea` field, but if you don't need to process it in the database, why not. That way you won't lose precision.

Comment: I tried this and this was the error which came in front:
 error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int’ in assignment

Second thing, i have to store double as bytea. it is necessary for the system

Comment: is it possible or is there any way to cast double to char?

Comment: You can cast `double` to `char` in C, but the result might not make you happy (remove decimal fraction, calculate the remainer for division by 256).

Comment: Is there any method to store the double* into database with bytea directly without casting it to char*?
PQexecparams required it to cast it to the char*. but i don't want to do that. I want to store it directly.

Comment: That *is* direct. All it does is to treat the value as a sequence of bytes rather than a `double`, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    paramLengths[3] = 10;
```

You've assigned an unused entry in `paramLengths`, and left the two entries for your two binary mode params uninitialized.

You're also *assuming* that your host's native format for `double` is the same as PostgreSQL's wire format for binary `double`. You need to make very sure that's the case, or convert to text-format. If you *are* going to pass `double*` values directly in the values array, you should at least set the corresponding lengths fields to `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: I have converted the double * into char* before inserting it. check this

const char* values[3] = {(const char *) valueX, nameString, (const char *) valueY };

Then i insert it. In db, the type of these double arrays is bytea

Comment: Here is my create table code:



void CreateTableForBinary(PGconn *conn)
{


  // sql statement execute
    PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, "CREATE TABLE testData (ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, X bytea, Y bytea)");
    


  if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        cout << "Create testData table failed";
        PQclear(res);
        CloseConn(conn);
    }



  cout << "Create testData table - OK\n";

  // Clear result
  PQclear(res);


}

Comment: @MuhammadMubeen Please don't post code in comments please, it's generally illegible. And no, your code doesn't convert them to text-representations of floats in `char*`, you *cast* them to `char*`, so it's a mistyped pointer. You're still passing binary `double`, not character data. This isn't a postgres or libpq issue, it's a C/C++ issue.

Comment: sorry for posting the code i will not do that again. Second thing, it is mandatory to cast double* to char* before insertion because values[] only accept the char*. Is there any other method to cast them?

Comment: If you actually intend to pass the byte value of the double, it's fine to cast them. It's only if you thought that would convert them to a text representation that it would be a problem.

Comment: you mean to say that we cannot cast double into char?

Comment: is it possible or is there any way to cast double to char?

Comment: Is there any method to store the double* into database with bytea directly without casting it to char*?
PQexecparams required it to cast it to the char*. but i don't want to do that. I want to store it directly.

Comment: @MuhammadMubeen `char*` in C effectively means "pointer to byte(s)". So that's what you want. I think you need to revisit the basics here a bit more, there are too many points of confusion/misunderstanding for this to be easily done on SO.